# PHP socket_close() Not Closing Server Connections

Tags: php, sockets

I am doing a 2 part app that requires two different socket connections to Window-based apps.

My app:  Opens to read and query from an appliance via Socket #1.  Socket #2 opens at the same time as Socket #1 to another appliance and waits to send commands to that appliance.

Both work fine for reading and sending as expected.

What I am running into is that I close Socket #2 on my side (client) the appliance side still shows an active connection and never seems to close them -- there are connections for a few days on there.

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($sock, $host, $port) or die('ERROR');

socket_write($sock, $buffer, $len);
print_r(simplexml_load_string(socket_read($sock, 65535)));

socket_shutdown($sock, 2);
socket_close($sock);
```

I have tried socket_shutdown + socket_close, I have changed methods to pfsocketopen/fclose, fsocketopen/fclose, etc.  I am not even sure there is anything I can do.

Thoughts?

Comment: I had this issue once when communicating with HP-UX.  The issue was that the remote side of the connection HAD to make the shutdown request before the client side.  Otherwise, the sockets would linger on the remote side in a TIMEOUT_WAIT status forever.  Is there anything you can send to the service telling it that the work is complete?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation and nothing in the sample code C# code they sent.  The socket connect string is pretty much the same between mine and theirs.  I had been looking at the linger option for socket to see if I could set that and have it know to time out after like 30 minutes -- problem is that these sessions could be a few hours long and not sure how many commands I would send over that time.

Comment: So I tried a whole bunch of different things.  Turns out that if I ctrl+c from the command line that will do it.  So updated to send a ^C through the socket and its all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a whole bunch of different things. Turns out that if I ctrl+c from the command line that will do it. So updated to send a ^C through the socket and its all good

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and this worked for me.

1. You'll need to set the [Linger](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-option.php) options, and for this to work you will need to be in `block`mode.

> If l_onoff is non-zero and l_linger is zero, all the unsent data will be discarded and RST (reset) is sent to the peer in the case of a connection-oriented socket.

2. Then use [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to

> Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or
> exit() is called.

```
// After socket_create $s
socket_set_block($s);

// Set Linger Options ($o)
$o=['l_onoff'=>1, 'l_linger'=>0];
socket_set_option($s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, $o);

// Use register shutdown to trigger socket shutdown and close
register_shutdown_function('socket_shutdown', $s,2);
register_shutdown_function('socket_close', $s);

// do the rest of your stuff
```

This worked for me flawlessly about 10 times in a row. I was even able to CTRL-C the server, restart it in the seconds and send more from the client without him even noticing. For your reference and proof-of-work see working code snippet below.

---

- Seems to be working without registering the shutdown function
- The ending close function is most likely obsolete but haven't got there yet.
- Client will loop for input (and press ENTER) and echo the server's response.
- Server will echo message sent from the client and send it back to the client.

server.php

```
<?php
$h="localhost";
$p=65535;
set_time_limit(0);
$s=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("create\n");

// START
socket_set_block($s);
$o=['l_onoff'=>1, 'l_linger'=>0];
socket_set_option($s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, $o);
register_shutdown_function('socket_shutdown', $s,2);
register_shutdown_function('socket_close', $s);
// END

socket_bind($s, $h, $p) or die("bind\n");
socket_listen($s, 3) or die("listen\n");
while(true) {
  $a=socket_accept($s);# or die("accept\n");
  $i=socket_read($a, 1024);# or die("read\n");
  if($a && $i):
    echo $o='Client message:'.$i.PHP_EOL."\n";
    socket_write($a, $o, strlen ($o)) or die("write\n");
  endif;
  socket_close($a);
}
socket_close($s);
```

client.php

```
<?php
$h="127.0.0.1";
$p=65535;
while(true){
  echo "Input: \n";
  $i=trim(fgets(fopen("php://stdin","r")));
  $s=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("create\n");

  // START
  socket_set_block($s);
  $o=['l_onoff'=>1, 'l_linger'=>0];
  socket_set_option($s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, $o);
  register_shutdown_function('socket_shutdown', $s,2);
  register_shutdown_function('socket_close', $s);
  // END

  if($i&&$s):
    socket_connect($s, $h, $p) or die("connect\n");  
    socket_write($s, $i, strlen($i)) or die("write\n");
    $o=socket_read($s, 1024) or die("read\n");
    echo 'Server response: '.$o.PHP_EOL;
  endif;
}
socket_close($s);
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved my many days problem. At the end after tests for me was enough only two lines: $o=['l_onoff'=>1, 'l_linger'=>0];
socket_set_option($s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, $o);